# Numpy: Select columns two by two

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array

I'm working on beginner data analysis with `numpy` on Python. I've this piece of code:

```
## column = [product]
## row = [client]
## value 1 means that a product has been purchased .
 
cart = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 1],
                 [1, 0, 1, 1],
                 [1, 1, 0, 0],
                 [0, 1, 1, 1]])
```

I want to know how can I select the columns above two by two to print at the end how much each pairs of products were purchased. Also I need to find which pair of products was the most purchased.

Where each tuple (u, v, n) means that products u and v are purchased together n times (per n customers).
The output will be:

```
[(0,1,2), (0,2,2), (0,3,2), (1,2,2), (1,3,2), (2,3,3)]
(2,3,3) ->  the most purchased.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick and easy solution which produces the list of purchase pairs and the most purchased.

Essentially the code just iterates the column pairs (created by `combinations`), and sums each pair. The pairs whose sum equals 2, are summed to derive the count of sold pairs.

Setup:

```
a = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 1],
              [1, 0, 1, 1],
              [1, 1, 0, 0],
              [0, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Sample code:

```
from itertools import combinations

results = []
for i, j in combinations([0, 1, 2, 3], 2):
    results.append((i, j, (a[:,[i,j]].sum(axis=1) == 2).sum()))
    
max_ = max(results, key=sum)

print(results)
print(f'Max result: {max_}')
```

Output:

```
[(0, 1, 2), (0, 2, 2), (0, 3, 2), (1, 2, 2), (1, 3, 2), (2, 3, 3)]
Max result: (2, 3, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to loop on every pair combination. This is essentially `range(cart.shape[1]) x range(cart.shape[1])`, i.e two `for` loops.

For a given product index `u` the corresponding vector is `cart[:, u]`. To compare two products vectors we can apply the dot product: `cart[:, u]*cart[:,v]`. The resulting vector will hold a `1` if both products were bought by the same client. To count the number of clients having bought both of these products, we can sum the vector.

Here is the expanded version:

```
p = range(cart.shape[1])
res = []
for u in p:
  for v in p:
    if u < v:
      res.append((u, v, sum(cart[:,u]*cart[:,v])))
```

Or in one go with a list comprehension:

```
p = range(cart.shape[1])
[(u, v, sum(cart[:,u]*cart[:,v])) for u in p for v in p if u < v]
```